# Audio Encryption Using RSA

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

When i run the below code the decrypted length is different from the original length. So the audio can't be read.

I get this error : javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream

```
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1119)
at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:119)
```

My code is here:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

public class MainClass {
public static final int SIZE = 1024;

private BigInteger p, q, n, totient, e, d;
private Random rnd = new Random();

public MainClass() {

    p = new BigInteger(1024, 10, new Random());
    do {
        q = new BigInteger(1024, 10, new Random());
    } while (p.equals(q));

    n = p.multiply(q);

    totient = (p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(q
            .subtract(BigInteger.ONE));

    // System.out.println(p+"\n"+q+"\n"+n+"\n"+totient);
}

public BigInteger getMod() {
    d = e.modInverse(totient);
    // System.out.println("d="+d);
    return d;
}

public BigInteger getE() {
    do {
        e = new BigInteger(SIZE, rnd);
    } while (!e.gcd(totient).equals(BigInteger.ONE)
            || !(e.compareTo(totient) < 0));
    return e;
}

public String encrypt(String msg) {
    BigInteger ciphertext = new BigInteger(msg.getBytes());
    String cipher = (ciphertext).modPow(getE(), getN()).toString();
    return cipher;
}

public String decrypt(String msg) {
    byte[] decryptMsg = (new BigInteger(msg)).modPow(getMod(), getN())
            .toByteArray();
    String plain = new String(decryptMsg);
    return plain;
}

public BigInteger getN() {
    return n;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        List<String> ori = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> st1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> st2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        String s2;

        MainClass mc = new MainClass();
        // StringHelper sh = new StringHelper();
        byte[] input;
        final ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // final AudioFileFormat.Type [] types =
        // AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes();
        final String PATH = "C:\\Users\\Rahul\\Desktop\\adios.wav";
        final AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem
                .getAudioInputStream(new File(PATH));

        AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,
                byteOut);
        audioInputStream.close();
        byteOut.close();
        input = ((ByteArrayOutputStream) byteOut).toByteArray();
        System.out.println(input.length);

        input.toString();
        String s = new String(input);
        System.out.println("Original " + s.length() + "\n");

        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i + 255 < s.length(); i = i + 256) {
            ori.add(s.substring(i, i + 255));
        }
        ori.add(s.substring(i - 256, s.length() - 1));
        // System.out.println(s.length());
        for (i = 0; i < ori.size(); i++) {
            st1.add(mc.encrypt(ori.get(i)));
        }
        // String s1 = mc.encrypt(s.substring(0, 500));

        // System.out.println("Cipher Text");
        // System.out.println(s1.length()+ "\n"+s1);
        for (i = 0; i < st1.size(); i++) {
            st2.add(mc.decrypt(st1.get(i)));
        }
        // String s2 = mc.decrypt(s1);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (i = 0; i < st2.size(); i++) {
            sb.append(st2.get(i));
        }
        s2 = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("Decrypt" + s2.length() + "\n");
        byte[] output = s2.getBytes();
        ByteArrayInputStream oInstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(output);
        AudioInputStream oAIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(oInstream);
        AudioSystem.write(oAIS, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File(
                "E:\\decrypted.wav"));
        oAIS.close();
        oInstream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Any help??

Comment: You shouldn't be using Strings like that.  Probably not at all.

Comment: Please: 1. Don't implement crypto yourself (recommended by Boneh in https://www.coursera.org/#course/crypto), find a library. 2. Don't use RSA to directly encrypt data streams. Encrypt some 128+ bit "session key" and use symmetric algorithm: AES or any other modern block or stream cipher. 3. Test your encryption/decryption on some test vector before using it with some useful data (audio in your case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is broken in many ways:

1. You're using an insecure PRNG
2. `p` and `q` should be primes
3. You're not using padding. RSA requires padding, preferably OAEP
4. You're open to timing attacks
5. RSA can only encrypt a few bytes at once. In practice we rarely encrypt actual data with RSA. It's *slow*, it increases the size of the ciphertext, there is no standardized mode for this,...
6. Abuse of strings. Your conversion from `string` to `BigInteger` is nonsense. You shouldn't use strings at all, you should work with binary data directly.
7. Not a real problem, but in practice we choose `e` to be a small prime larger than two such as 3 or 65537. This results in a significant speedup of public key operations.

How you should do this:

1. Use Java's built in RSA
2. Generate a new random AES key and encrypt it with RSA
3. Encrypt actual data with AES in an authenticated mode (AES-GCM for example)
4. Concat the results of 2. and 3.

Comment: @GregS I don't think UTF-8 fits anywhere here. Audio files are binary, no reason to use strings or UTF-8 here.

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking at the encrypt() method which takes the `msg` to be encrypted and uses `msg.toBytes()`. Actually I think the exception has nothing to do with the crypt at all.

Comment: @CodesInChaos  Thanks will try to do it with binary data.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be trying to re-invent the wheel, while making it square into the bargain. Java has a built-in encryption API which I would strongly advise you to use. And you also need to get a full grasp of which encryption to use where.

A key problem you have, aside from your implementation, is that RSA is designed for passing a very small piece of data-- essentially, a key for another algorithm actually used to perform the encryption of the main data. Or put another way if this helps: think of RSA as essentially a key passing scheme, not an "encryption" algorithm per se.

You should:

- using the standard encryption library, encrypt the data using a symmetric algorithm such as AES: see, for example, my tutorial on [symmetric/AES encryption in Java](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/symmetric.shtml)
- use RSA only as a means of passing to the remote client the (AES etc) key that you used to encrypt the data: again, I've written about [using RSA in Java](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml) with example code.

I would also really encourage you to read through mine and other people's tutorials to really try and understand what is going on with cryptography. It's quite a complex area and just "diving in" without a good understanding of the basic concepts is likely to lead to you writing insecure code.